# Use custom name for table in \listoftables when using \captionof{table}{...} in the document

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, captions

I decided to use `\captionof{table}{bar}` for writing captions for tables in my thesis, but I cannot find a way to use another text `foo` in the `\listoftables` instead without using `\begin{table} ... \end{table}` together with `\caption[foo]{bar}`. Is there an alternative so I can leave everything as is?

Thank You very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\captionof` command from the caption package offers an optional argument, just as the `\caption` command does:

`\captionof{<float type>}[<list entry>]{<heading>}`

Adapted to your example, this would translate to: `\captionof{table}[foo]{bar}`

Comment: Thank You very much! This did the trick for me. I tried things like `\captionof[foo]{table}{bar}` for way too long...